# Pass date paramater to grep in bash

Tags: bash, date, grep

Want to pass the current month to grep so it lists current month's logins for a specific user.
Script below does echo the current month, ($mnth), but grep doesn't do anything with it.
If I hard code the month("Sep") instead of $mnth, I get the correct output - last month of logons.   I guess working solution should apply to the year "2020" also.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                       
echo -e '\n'                                                                              
echo $SHELL                                                                                        
echo -e '\n'   
mnth=$(date +%b)                                                                   
echo $mnth                                                                          

last -F john_paul_jones | grep -E '$mnth ([ 1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)' | grep 2020 |more
```

**Thanx**

Comment: use double quotes if you want $mnth to resolve in the grep expression. single quote tell the command interpreter not to replace $var with its value try echo '$mnth' and echo "$mnth" to see the difference

Comment: You should almost always double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$SHELL"` instead of `echo $SHELL`) (and, as Rob said, *don't* single-quote them). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Comment: Shellcheck.net is preety coool.  Not many people were I work are very good at bash scripting.   I enclosed $mnth in double quotes,  Got the same result (grep didn't do anything with it, no results).  Shellcheck.net had a line just below with an arrow pointing to  '"$mnth" saying          "expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes instead".          But I did use double quotes...